# Codeigniter url path?

Tags: codeigniter

I have the login form and path is this

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/login/
```

Once user enter the value I do validation

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/login/validation
```

after validation I want to redirect the user to main_page controller , If I load the view of main page it does load the view but path remain same in browser

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/login/validation
```

Where as I want that when the validation is successfull it should show me this path

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/main_page
```

I tried loading controller of main_page but it show me blank page, in main_page controller index function I am loading the view of main page .

Comment: you should use redirect method as @Rooneyl has stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect user after login abd change the URL use the redirect function.
Something like;

```
public function login() {
    if($this->form_validation->run('login') == TRUE ) {
        // $redirect is what ever page you want to go to
        redirect($redirect);
    } else {
        // show form
        $this->load->view('login_form');
    }
}
```